# Spring MVC : retrieve Http Request header

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I implemented a micro-services architecture. Before accessing each micro-service the request gets through a gateway that checks the authentication and in the process adds an `X-User` header containing the user id.

In each of my micro-services, I would like to be able to retrieve this user (`X-User`) in an elegant way: without adding the `HttpRequest`/`@RequestHeader` to all my Controllers and pass it to the services, etc.

*Using something like "`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getUserId();`" would be perfect but as I don't manage the Authentication in my micro services it's not possible.*

Comment: You could use a [custom filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter)

Comment: Your question lacks clarity, where do you want to retrieve the value and how do you intend to use it(at least where)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to:

1. implement a Servlet `Filter` (see [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter) for details) that gets the `userId` from the `ServletRequest` and stores it in a `ThreadLocal` (see [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal) for details)
2. retrieve that `ThreadLocal` from any class that would need the `userId`

Good luck!